# JQuery Script link placement in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am a little confused since I am a beginning.
I just started learning JQuery using Codecademy's tutorial.

They say I should put all Scripts just before the end of the `</body>` tag of an `HTML` document.

[image: Snippet from Codecademy]

I then read what W3SChools have said and they recommend putting this in the `<head>` of an `HTML` document.

[image: Snippet from W3SChools]

If someone could clarify what the best practice is that would really help. Unless there isn't a difference, then I apologise for my naivety.

Comment: W3Schools are idiots, be wary of the 'advice' they offer. http://w3fools.com

Comment: That said, either will work. The difference is the point at which your JS code gets loaded. Placing the script before `</body>` is slightly faster.

Comment: **Do not follow w3schools.com!!!**

Comment: @PraveenKumar could you suggest a better repository to help me if I should not follow w3schools?

Comment: You can always use [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/)...